# Error setting widget parameters using VoidCallback in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call a widget with parameter VoidCallback, But when I want to call that widget, there is an error on press: () {   }

Here error message : [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veb4L.png) ( Invalid constant value. )

**profile_menu.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class ProfileMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileMenu({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    this.press,
  });

  final String text, icon;
  final VoidCallback? press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: press,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              icon,
              width: 22,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(child: Text(text)),
            const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**profile_screen.dart**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Profile"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: const SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "Profile",
              icon: "assets/icons/Profile Icon.svg",
              press: () {
                print('a');
              }
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "Account",
              icon: "assets/icons/Account Icon.svg",
              press: () {
                print("b");
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How to set the press parameter when we call a widget?

Comment: remove const from `body:  SingleChildScrollView(`

Comment: Thank you so much @Md.YeasinSheikh. I've fixed my code for anyone.

Comment: @Manami please don't fix the problem in your question, because it no longer makes sense to other people stumbling upon the same problem and finding your question

Comment: @Albert221 sure, I've updated to the original error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `const` before your `SingleChildScrollView`. The callback you pass to `ProfileMenu.press` is not a constant, so the `ProfileMenu` cannot be a constant. Because of that, `SingleChildScrollView` (its parent) cannot be constant too.

You can make the `SizedBox` widgets and the `EdgeInsets` constant though.